# Select a part of a vector with C++ and Eigen

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, eigen, eigen3

I would like to select a part of a vector in C++ with the library Eigen?

I mean if I have this vector :

```
VectorXd v(6);
v << 1, 2, 3, 8, 1, 2;
```

Is there a function which returns this vector:

```
a << 2, 8, 2;
```

?

Because I know how to select just a part of a vector but only with a step of one not two.

Answer (score 2):

There is no function that does this super specific thing. If it did it would probably be under [eigen block operations](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialBlockOperations.html). Your best bet is going to be to write your own function. Something similar to this:

```
void addConsecutiveSpacedElements(VectorXd &out, const VectorXd &in, int start, int space) {
    int index = 0;
    for (int in_index = start, in_index < in.size(); in_index += space) {
        out[index++] = in[in_index];
    }
}

...

addConsecutiveSpacedElements(a, v, 1, 2);
```

*Note: This is essentially pseudo code and therefore has no error checking etc. It is also untested.*